# Why is Safari displaying scrambled graphics?

Tags: macos, safari, graphics

When I click on "new tab" in safari, I see this flicker often as a new tab is opening:

[image: Safari new tab messed up]

Any idea why this is? It seems to be a scrambled cache of my graphics card... (In case you're wondering, the sushi stuff is from my iOS game, [Nippon](http://iTunes.com/apps/nippon).)

Comment: I have the same problem, wondering why....

Comment: I have exactly the same problem (the screen scrambling looks identical) but I"m running Windows XP, so this can't be endemic to Mac Operating systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't so much a Safari problem as it is an OS X / hardware one. I'm going to guess that you have Intel or Nvidia graphics on a MacBook (Pro).

It's well-documented; there are lots of people with these issues (including myself). As far as I've found, you can't fix it. Just restart or wait it out.

Sorry I can't be more useful.

Comment: Great, just wanted a confirmation. So this is essentially a graphics card quirk, yes?

Comment: @Moshe The best explanation I've been able to get is that it has to do with how the OS interacts with the graphics card. In any case, it's something pretty low-level. Nothing that a user can fix/change, or is causing.